# Error in opening rasterfile with ArcView 3.2

Tags: raster, error, arcview-3

I'm working the first time with ArcView 3.2, but have worked with ArcMap Desktop. I did all the preprocessing of my data in ArcMap, but need a tool (AVErosion) that is just available for ArcView. 
My problem is, that all the rasterfiles (.tif) I created just appear as a black blank square in ArcView. In ArcMap and other programs they appear just fine and with information in it.
Does anyone have a clue? I already got the extension 'TIFF 6.0 Image Support' activated.

Comment: I would suggest using QGIS (Community Supported) and not a discontinued ESRI product. The most likely problem is that your tiff is a different compression to what ArcView can handle - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Compression_2

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, but I wanna use the tool AVErosion that in the moment just exists for ArcView.. but thank you!

Comment: QGIS has Universal Soil Loss Equation (USLE) tools  https://www.ijsr.net/conf/NCKITE2015/78.pdf

Comment: Related (for QGIS) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30240/how-to-calculate-ls-factor-of-watershed-for-rusle-calculation

Comment: I'm working with a modification of the USLE that is especially adapted to conditions in Germany, called ABAG. But if it doesn't work out with ArcView I will have to build the formula on my own probably in ArcMap

Comment: Have you tried applying the tool and gotten any results?  I don't think 3x applies a stretch to rasters, so the data may be there but just not easily viewable in a meaningful way.

Comment: The solution was converting the data to GRID format in ArcMap. Then I could open it in ArcView